How to add categories in `free` command
I can extract the amount of memory used by running the following two commands from terminal:
free -h | awk '/^Mem:/ {print $3}' This shows the used memory, e.g. 4.8Gi.
free -h | awk '/^Mem:/ {print $5}' This shows the shared memory e.g. 906Mi.
I would like a single command to print the sum of both results. How can I achieve it?

Related: ps_mem utility to accurately report the core memory usage

Instead of converting between multiple possible units in each column, you can output both columns in plain bytes using free -b and do the conversion in Awk itself
free -b | awk '/^Mem:/ { printf "%.2f Gi\n", ($3+$5)/1024/1024/1024 }'


Wow! Impressive! Thanks very much.

Is there a way to get rid of the inner ".."? I need to use it in a context which already includes quotation marks on the outside..

Did you mean to get rid of the space between the value and the unit Gi? Just change the printf to not include it, i.e. printf "%.2fGi\n", ($3+$5)/1024/1024/1024

No I meant the quotes themselves "

That shouldn't have an impact wherever else you are using outside? Can you show how exactly are you running it?

I am using it in awesomewm; I managed to do it eventually by double escaping the ". E.g. myFreeMemory = awful.widget.watch('bash -c "free -b | awk \'/^Mem:/ { printf \\"%.2f/%i\\", ($3+$5)/1024/1024/1024, $2/1024/1024/1024 }\'"', 1)

Thanks very much. If there is no other way then this is fine..
